# EF and design pattern

Tags: entity-framework, architecture

I’m working on a high volume transactional enterprise application(asp.net, windows app, oracle app as client) which has been designed using n-tire application and SOA architecture .The application was developed in the .NET platform utilizing C#,VB.NET, Framework 3.5 (I’m planning to upgrade to the , Framework 4.0), EF( EF in the data layer level) and WCF(WCF services in  the  service layer level)
Since this is the first project using EF, and having read about using EF in n-tier and SOA applications, and the features available in the EF Feature, I have the following points:

- Which design pattern should I use in EF( Simple Entities, Change Set, Self-Tracking Entities and DTOs) in  the data layer level
- In addition Which design pattern should I use in the other tier and layer to get the best practices of EF

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"In addition Which design pattern should I use in the other tier and layer to get the best practices of EF "

- I would use the saperation of concerns using IoC at the root of my design patterns. for Data Layer Abstraction purpose I would definately go for Repository patterns. There are some interesting work which you see on the web for e.g. UnitOfWork for transactions etc.

Not sure about your knowledge in Repository pattern but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c)'s a good start.

There is also a good project on the CodePlex called [Project Silk](http://silk.codeplex.com/) which can give you a good heads up for both the above topics among others.

All the best